# Can I dynamically discover xml files in the classpath inside an EJB 3 container?

Tags: java, xml, ejb-3.0, classpath

**Background:**

One of the components of our project operates using spring.  Some SQL code is dynamically generated, based on a given XML spring configuration.

At first it was fine to store all the XML configurations in the same package on the classpath, (and then load it as a resource when the service is called) but over time we ended up with a large number of configurations.  It came time to separate the configurations into different namespaces.

**The Goal**

What I want is, given a starting package on the classpath, to recursively walk the directory structure and discover any spring XML files dynamically.  (So that as new configurations / packages are added, the files will still be found by the service).

**The Problem**

I was able to accomplish my goal fine when running outside an EJB container by using `Thread.getContextClassloader().getResource(myBasePackage)`, then getting a File object and using it to walk the tree on the filesystem.  Clunky, I know, but it was still classpath relative and it worked.

However, you cannot do this inside an EJB container (you can't interact with the filesystem at all), so I had to use the rather annoying workaround in which I maintain a list of hardcoded packages to search.

**The Question**

*Is there a way (running inside an EJB container) to dynamically walk the classpath (from a given starting location) searching for arbitrary resources?*

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to do it via a hook to the file system.  I'm wondering if there's a dynamic way to search for classpath resources, not files.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not while staying in compliance with the EJB spec. Because the spec envisions containers running in all kinds of non-standard situations, it does not make this possible.

Longer answer: Since you are not creating these resources dynamically, I would write a routine that gives you a list of all of the resources at build time and puts them in a dynamically generated file that your EJB knows how to reference. So you basically create a directory listing of packages and files that you can load in the EJB that are referenced in one master file.

Spring answer: Spring supports finding resources on the classpath, although I have no idea how well this works in the EJB context (and I doubt its EJB compliant, but I haven't checked). Some details [here](http://www.crazymcphee.net/x/2010/04/29/dynamically-loading-spring-contexts-from-the-classpath-at-runtime/).

Comment: Obviously not the answer I was hoping for, but building the list dynamically at build time could be an option.  But it seems about equivalent to maintaining the hardcoded package list. (OK, slightly better).

Comment: Also, I already know that it works under Spring, (but its not EJB compliant, as you say).

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: As already pointed out, creating resources in the classpath is not recommended and depending on the EJB container explicitly forbidden. This may cause you a lot of problems because containers may explode your resources into another folder or even replicate the resources throughout the cluster (if thats the case). In order to create resources dynamically you have to create a custom classloader. So, I would never do it. It is better to access the filesystem directly than the classpath. It is less ugly and eventually cluster-safe if you use a remote filesystem + file locks.

If even after all I explained you still want to play with the classpath, you can try to do something like: get the classloader via

```
ClassLoader cld = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

Starting from a base package enumerate all occurrences

```
Enumeration<URL> basePackageUrls = cld.getResources(basePackagePath);
```

Each URL is generally either a file link (file:///home/scott/.../MyResource.properties)  or a jar link (file:///lib.jar!/com/domain/MyResource.properties). You have to check the pattern in the URL. Using that, enumerate the contents of the folder using the normal java API and find the subpackages. Proceed until you have scanned all packages.

See the class below (will be released with an open-source project of mine soon). It implemens a classpath scanner that you can pass in a selector. It works like a visitor. It my work for you, if not, get ideas from it. See the sample annotation selector at the end.

```
public class ClasspathScanner
{

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ClasspathScanner.class);
    private static final String JAR_FILE_PATTERN = ".jar!";

    private ClassSelector selector;
    private Set<Class<?>> classes;

    // PUBLIC METHODS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public synchronized Set<Class<?>> scanPackage(String basePackage, ClassSelector selector)
        throws Exception
    {
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Selector cannot be NULL");
        }
        this.selector = selector;
        this.classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        Set<Class<?>> aux;
        try
        {
            scanClasses0(basePackage);
            aux = this.classes;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.selector = null;
            this.classes = null;
        }

        return aux;
    }

    // HELPER CLASSES ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void scanClasses0(String basePackage)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        File packageDirectory = null;
        ClassLoader cld = getLoader();
        String basePackagePath = basePackage.replace('.', '/');
        Enumeration<URL> basePackageUrls = cld.getResources(basePackagePath);
        if (basePackageUrls == null || !basePackageUrls.hasMoreElements())
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Base package path not found: [" + basePackagePath
                + "]");
        }
        while (basePackageUrls.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String packagePath = basePackageUrls.nextElement().getFile();
            if (packagePath.contains(JAR_FILE_PATTERN))
            {
                scanJarFile(basePackagePath, packagePath);
            }
            else
            {
                packageDirectory = new File(packagePath);
                scanDirectory(basePackage, packageDirectory);
            }
        }
    }

    private void scanDirectory(String packageName, File packagePath)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        if (packagePath.exists())
        {
            File[] packageFiles = packagePath.listFiles();
            for (File file : packageFiles)
            {
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                {
                    String fullFileName = packageName + '.' + file.getName();
                    checkClass(fullFileName);
                }
                else if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                    scanDirectory(packageName + "." + file.getName(), file);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(packagePath.getPath());
        }
    }

    private void scanJarFile(String basePackagePath, String jarFileUrl)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String jarFilePath = jarFileUrl.substring("file:".length(), jarFileUrl
            .indexOf(JAR_FILE_PATTERN)
            + JAR_FILE_PATTERN.length() - 1);
        log.debug("URL JAR file path: [" + jarFilePath + "]");
        jarFilePath = URLDecoder.decode(jarFilePath, "UTF-8");
        log.debug("Decoded JAR file path: [" + jarFilePath + "]");
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(new File(jarFilePath));
        for (Enumeration<JarEntry> jarFiles = jar.entries(); jarFiles.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            JarEntry file = jarFiles.nextElement();
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (!file.isDirectory() && fileName.endsWith(".class")
                && fileName.startsWith(basePackagePath))
            {
                String className = fileName.replace('/', '.');
                checkClass(className);
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkClass(String fullFilePath) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String className = fullFilePath.substring(0, fullFilePath.length() - 6);
        Class<?> c = getLoader().loadClass(className);
        if (selector.select(c))
        {
            classes.add(c);
        }
    }

    private ClassLoader getLoader()
    {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if (loader == null)
        {
            loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        return loader;
    }

    // INNER CLASSES -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public interface ClassSelector
    {
        boolean select(Class<?> clazz);
    }

    public static class AnnotatedClassSelector implements ClassSelector
    {
        private final Class<? extends Annotation>[] annotations;

        public AnnotatedClassSelector(Class<? extends Annotation>... annotations)
        {
            this.annotations = annotations;
        }

        public boolean select(Class<?> clazz)
        {
            for (Class<? extends Annotation> ac : annotations)
            {
                if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(ac))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I originally tried, and as you predicted, it doesn't work (maybe depending on the EJB implementation).  It doesn't work in JBOSS anyway.  (But I didn't need to implement a custom classloader, just get the Enumeration of URLs as you suggested.)  Anyway, I agree this solution is dangerous because it isn't allowed in the EJB spec, so I would prefer the somewhat clunky "static" solution than a dangerous dynamic one.